# same-length same-signedness integer types in template parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

When being used as template parameters, are integer types of the same length and the same signedness considered equal, i.e., do they produce the same template class when being used as a template parameter? Which paragraph of the spec handles this case?

E.g., consider I am on an architecture on which `unsigned` and `unsigned long` are both 32-bit, then will for example a `vector<unsigned>` be another class as a `vector<unsigned long>` or will they be treated as the same type?

Comment: It should take you about a minute to figure it out yourself, simply by trying to compile `std::vector<unsigned> a; std::vector<unsigned long> b; b=a;`. There's no reason to wait until some stranger on stackoverflow.com answers a simple question one can figure out on their own.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The question could logically have three answers: sometimes, always, and never; testing could eliminate one, but the other two would remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are guaranteed to be different types. This is clarified by a note in the standard:

> Even if the implementation defines two or more basic types to have the same value representation,
>   they are nevertheless different types.

([basic.fundamental]/11)

In general, two types are only the same if one is aliased to the other (*i.e.,* with `typedef` or `using`) or if both are aliased to the same type.

Given that `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are different types, `vector<unsigned int>` and `vector<unsigned long>` are also different types, even if the two classes have identical layouts.

Comment: If the reason the OP asked is to find out if there will be "template bloat" caused by two instantiations where one would suffice, we still can't know based on this info.  An implementation could collapse the two instantiations if it wanted to--I'm almost certain.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a blind type-cast between different integer types then the cast will work sometimes, but necessarily every time.  This is because different types have different minimum and maximum values.  Type casting will be allowed by most compilers but they will use rules that you may not be familiar with resulting in potentially unexpected behaviour.  The best thing to do is to research these types and then ensure that any code you write that converts between them prevents unpredictable results.

Comment: Unfortunately, even on implementations where "int" and "long" have identical representations in all cases, a compiler is still allowed to regard operations on "int" and "long" as being unsequenced with regard to each other, thus rewriting "*intPtr=5; long x=*longPtr;" as "long x=*longPtr; *intPtr=5;".